# Sublime Text subl shortcut not working: ln: /Users/edmundmai/bin/subl: No such file or directory

Tags: sublimetext2

Hi I am trying to set up the terminal shortcut for sublime text 2(`subl`) but it's not working. I'm following the directions on https://github.com/mhartl/rails_tutorial_sublime_text/blob/master/README.md but can't get past the first step.

When I type:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

I receive the error

```
ln: /Users/edmundmai/bin/subl: No such file or directory
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This probably means that there is no `~/bin` directory.  Which also probably means that it isn't in the `PATH`.  So just continue on to the next suggestion:

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl
```

Comment: This worked for Sublime Text 3 as well (changing the name of the app of course). Thank you!

Comment: yes it did work for Sublime Text 3, changing app name from 'Sublime Text 2.app' to just 'Sublime Text.app'. So the whole command is **sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl**

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively you can put it to your local bin:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

it may need creating the bin beforehand:

```
mkdir /usr/local/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

Another approach is define subl as your shell alias

http://opensourcehacker.com/2012/05/11/sublime-text-2-tips-for-python-and-web-developers/#Open_files_from_command-line

This is the recommended approach as it is against the best practices to add symlinks in /usr/bin