# Sublime terminal command line creations producing multiple errors

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, anaconda, sublimetext3

I have tried numerous articles/git reps/stack overflow posts, nothing is allowing me to simply access sublime through my terminal. I have a `/usr/local/bin` $PATH and still get the error:

```
ln: /usr/local/bin/subl: No such file or directory
```

I ran this block of code that is on the sublime website to get the error:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

Some of what I've tried is in the links below; any input or thoughts would be appreciated

https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html

https://olivierlacan.com/posts/launch-sublime-text-3-from-the-command-line/

[Sublime Text subl shortcut not working: ln: /Users/edmundmai/bin/subl: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12326098/sublime-text-subl-shortcut-not-working-ln-users-edmundmai-bin-subl-no-such-f)

Comment: Please always write the complete `ln` command you entered, which gave you the error message. Asides from this, I don't see why it should be related to your `PATH`. The error message simply says that `/usr/local/bin/subl` does not exist, which is something you can verify by yourself by doing a `ls -ld /usr/local/bin/subl`.

Comment: `ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl` creates a `subl` link in the `bin` directory in your [home directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Home_directory) (the `~` expands to the path to your home directory).  On macOS that will be something like '/Users/r9t/bin/subl', not '/usr/local/bin/subl'.

Comment: See "[Don’t use “click here” and other common hyperlink mistakes](https://medium.com/@heyoka/dont-use-click-here-f32f445d1021)", "[Don't use "click here" as link text](https://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)"
and "[Links and Hypertext - Link Text and Appearance](https://webaim.org/techniques/hypertext/link_text)". Please take the time to use more descriptive anchor text rather than toss out URLs.